# Inability to run flutter upgrade via the terminal

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to mobile app development and I started using flutter but of late I have been trying to upgrade my verison of flutter via the terminal but it's not working.And the image below is what it does

[A screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMf2W.jpg)

Comment: This is not an error this process takes time did you wait for a good few minutes (5-6 minutes or maybe wait for more than that)?

Comment: Can't see any error?